# Unable to update to java 8 in android studio

Tags: android, java-8

Below is my app.gradle apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.crayond.vlearning"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        incremental false
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':recyclerview')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.5'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.yalantis:phoenix:1.2.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   /* compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'*/
    annotationProcessor 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.1.0'
}
```

I get the following error while syncing gradle:
Error:Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.

Answer (score 0):

To update your android project jdk version to 1.8 use `retrolambda` library.

In your app level `build.gradle` file add:

**1.**

`apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'` in the top of the file.

**2.**

```
android{ 

    //Other stuff

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

**3.** And then add new dependency to your project level `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    //Other dependencies
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0'
}
```

Voila! Now you are able to use java 1.8 features in your android project.

Comment: That's a slight exaggeration. [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) would give the OP only support for lambdas and method references. That should also be possible with the "official" Android Studio toolchains, *Jack* (now deprecated) and [desugar](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html#supported_features). Things get a bit more interesting when you also need some new Java 8 API (say Streams) and at the same time want to have `minSdkVersion < 24`. If minSdkVersion is 24 or higher I would recommend to go with *desugar*.

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thanks for advice, seems I should get aquainted with desugar immediately.